# Redirect homepage but not if there are query strings present

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect just the homepage of a Wordpress site but only if the original URL does not have any query strings on it. This works:

```
RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ http://www.consumerenergyreport.com/ticker
```

...but redirects URLs with queries. I tried:

```
RewriteCond ! %{QUERY_STRING}
```

...but that doesn't seem to work with RedirectMatch, only RewriteRule (go fig).

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this rule in .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /ticker [R=307,L]
```